# What is the fastest way to copy files(db) between two volumes in linux in AWS?

Tags: linux, database, amazon-web-services, copy, snapshot

I have 2.5TB data in a 4TB volume that needs to be **copied to a *3 TB volume***. The IOPS is high for both the volumes due to their size. So technically , the transfer speed should be faster. **But since these are db files we need maintain File integrity,permissions,timestamps and all the stuff.**

Everyone recommends Rsync but also mention that it is slow. Is there any other faster method to copy while keeping the data integrity in check?

Also is there any way to say create a internal image of this volume like .img/iso etc and upload it to s3/google drive and download it in the other volume -- Just thinking all possibilities to get this done faster.

Update: Adding more info here - The volumes are attached to the same machine - 4TB is the volume with data. 3 TB is the new empty volume. This is essentially part of volume resize activity.

Comment: Why does speed matter in this case? Is this going to happen on a regular basis, or is it just a one-off copy?

Comment: Just one time. Copying 3TB if it takes more than 5 days , we have a issue with replication. So trying to reduce the time as much as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test the speed of copying, I did the following:

- Launched a `t2.large` Amazon EC2 instance with:

  - A 4TB volume
  - A 3TB volume

[image: EBS volumes]

- On the 4TB volume: Generated 2.6TB of files, across 439 files:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.9G  416K  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  1.3G  6.8G  16% /
/dev/xvdb       3.9T  2.6T  1.2T  69% /v4t     <--- Generated files here
/dev/xvdc       2.9T   89M  2.8T   1% /v3t     <--- Target drive
tmpfs           798M     0  798M   0% /run/user/1000
```

I then copied the data overnight, resulting in:

```
/dev/xvdc       2.9T  2.6T  231G  92% /v3t
```

Copy speed was reported as:

```
sent 2,762,338,236,045 bytes  received 8,408 bytes  121,836,508.74 bytes/sec
total size is 2,761,663,971,512  speedup is 1.00
```

Unfortunately, my timer failed due to a disconnection, but it appears to have copied at a speed of about 1TB in 8 hours. So, it seems that you can copy your 2.5 TB overnight rather than needing 5 days.

Comment: what command did you use for copying? rsync or tar -c or something else?

Comment: I just used `rsync`. All files retained their original dates.

Comment: Maybe the number of files might've been lesser in your data. More number of files , no matter their size will contribute to increase in overall copy time. We used msrsync which runs rsync in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

If an "exact" copy of the disk is acceptable, then you could:

- Create a **Snapshot** of the Amazon EBS volume
- Create a **new Amazon EBS volume** from the snapshot
- Done!

Internally, the new volume "points to" the snapshot, so you don't have to wait for the data to be copied across. The first time a disk block is accessed, the block will be copied from the snapshot to the disk volume. This happens behind-the-scenes, so you won't even notice it. This means that the new volume is available very quickly.

However, please note that the new volume needs to be at least as big as the source volume.

Comment: It works for normal way @John , but here I'm copying the data to a smaller 3TB volume. So direct method of creating a volume from snapshot will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to John's answer, we used msrsync https://github.com/jbd/msrsync
Can run upto 16 threads of rsync in parallel. Since this was db, just the number of files we had was huge(irrespective of size). It took around 2 days for copying 2.5TB data.

Our db tables were fine and replication worked but we could still see differences in the size of data in the volumes. The newer volume had 160gb missing in the 2.5TB. This might be due to how the blocks were handled in the different volumes but we haven't seen any issue so far.